# what are { } used for in php?

Tags: php

Can anybody give good explain of meaning of { } in php?

In example, there is:

```
<?php

...

$site['mediaImages']       = "{$site['url']}media/images/";

...

?>
```

Not like classic if statement or function definition.

Comment: In this example, the brackets are useless. Otherwise, they would denote the end of the variable (if there is no space or something else, like [] in this case).

Comment: thanks, i editing some code my friend has write, but this is first time i see something like that. thanks a lot!

Comment: In that syntax they are NOT useless, because you can only use quoted array keys using the "complex syntax".

Comment: They're essentially useless here because he could also write `$site[url]media/images/`. You need the curlies to have the quoted keys, but you don't need the quoted keys in this case.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Exactly. They're already a string, they don't need to be *restrung* :) [CodePad](http://codepad.org/toty05Nr)

Comment: It lets you interpolate things like `"{$obj->something()}foobar"` for example, but in this case it does seem unnecessary although it's more clear the intention.

Answer (score 6):

The curly braces help PHP figure out where your variable ends.
For example

```
$hello = "hola";
echo "$helloworld"; // error: undefined variable $helloworld
echo "{$hello}world"; // echo "holaworld"
```

Comment: Additional info here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php Complex (curly) syntax

Answer (score 2):

It's the complex variable parsing syntax.

> This isn't called complex because the syntax is complex, but because
>   it allows for the use of complex expressions.
>
> Any scalar variable, array element or object property with a string
>   representation can be included via this syntax. Simply write the
>   expression the same way as it would appear outside the string, and
>   then wrap it in { and }. Since { can not be escaped, this syntax will
>   only be recognised when the $ immediately follows the {. Use {\$ to
>   get a literal {$. Some examples to make it clear:

Search for "Complex (curly) syntax" on this page: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: The direct link is http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex